# Why is the nested limits false

Tags: limits, analysis, derivatives

Assuming: $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=0$
\begin{gather*}
f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}\\
f''(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\color{blue}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{x}}\\
f''(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}}{x}=\color{red}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}}
\end{gather*}
L'Hospital's rule:$$\color{red}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{x}}$$
Why are the nested limits false?

Comment: Somewhat side-stepping the question, but in your context, $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}x = f'(0) \neq f'(x)$, so you cannot replace $f'(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}x$ anyway.

Comment: In addition to the issue Brian Moehring pointed out you have made the mistake of using the same symbol $x$ for two different things. 
$$f''(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}t-f(0)}{x-0}$$ would be proper. There are two separate limit processes in here, and you cannot combine them to one by letting them share the same variable approaching its limit.

Comment: Your meaning is that the $lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is a number,and the $f'(x)$ is a function ,so I cannot replace them?

Comment: That is correct Huyu. An expression that limits in $x$ cannot also be a function of $x$. $x$ is a dummy variable. You can replace: $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: oh,I understand it,thankyou a lot!  :)